# reusing view with multiple models in Sitecore MVC using glassmapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore7, glass-mapper, sitecore8

I'm having trouble determining how I might reuse views in my sitecore 8 solution using glassmapper.  I have two object that contain the same data, but the fields are named differently depending on the template.  Title vs Heading, for instance.

This is relatively simple when the page editor isn't a factor as I can just map/cast one object to another, but this seems to choke up the page editor.

The most obvious path is to use Interfaces and extension methods as described [here](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial21), but this requires creating a real kitchen sink of an Interface.

Any other suggestions?  I'd hate to copy the view just to change what properties it uses.

Comment: Maybe you need to re-think your templates, if the data is the same then separate out into a base template and then use template inheritance. You can then have a single class represent the data.

Comment: don't disagree, but not an option really.  Question is also more generic as well, perhaps one item has a generic link where the other item links to itself

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Controller Renderings then you could define an interface like so:

```
public interface ITitleAndBody : IGlassBase 
{
    string Title  {get; set;}
    string Body  {get; set;}
}
```

And concrete types like so:

```
public class MyType1 : GlassBase, ITitleAndBody 
{
    [SitecoreField("Title")]
    public virtual int Title  {get; set;}

    [SitecoreField("Body")]
    public virtual string Body  {get; set;}
}

public class MyType2 : MyType1
{
    [SitecoreField("Header")]
    public override int Title  {get; set;}
}
```

You will need two controller actions pointing to the same view:

```
public ActionResult MyType1()
{
    return PartialView("/Views/MyView.cshtml", SitecoreContext.GetCurrentItem<MyType1>());
}

public ActionResult MyType2()
{
    return PartialView("/Views/MyView.cshtml", SitecoreContext.GetCurrentItem<MyType2>());
}
```

And in the view itself use the interface as the model:

```
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<ITitleAndBody>

<div>@Editable(Model, x => x.Title)</div>
<p>@Editable(Model, x => x.Body)</p>
```

This is untested code. It would have been nicer to use View Renderings of course.

Answer (score 1):

Agree to what suggested by jammykam in his comment above - the most straightforward would be to rename template fields to be the same.

So, as per your example they will be all physically called **Title**; for content editors you may use help display name for particular field, so the will still see them as **Title** vs. **Heading**, despite in fact they both are called Title for the system. Of course, if your solution can allow renaming like that... More about this approach by the link: http://goo.gl/b28s2y (last part).

Another option to consider - you may think about proxy objects on top of your glass models that would re-map your field names to whatever you want. Thus passing your proxy objects having same names to a view.

But, right you are, in hardest case probably interfaces would be an answer

Comment: The proxy model sounds like what I am looking for, but when I attempted to 'map' it, it breaks the content editor as if it is losing the information needed to update the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, if the fields are same, you can change their titles on template's field properties. That way when I create an item of template X I would be presented with Field's title assigned on template X while the FieldName itself remains same.

But if I have to do it, I would prefer to use Interfaces with Glass.

Comment: I meant what jammykam commented.